# Hall effect sensor PWM matrix

Tags: hall-effect, matrix

Is it possible to set up a PWM output hall effect sensor in a matrix to reduce the number of GPIO pins required? I'm guessing not because there would always be a signal from the others in the row/column so it wouldn't register a change. I would think the signals are not additive

Comment: How many sensors do you want to use?  Are you thinking of devices such as TI [DRV5057](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv5057.pdf)?

Comment: between 40-50. And that is exactly what I'm using (or at least plan to use)

Comment: What speed of update do you want?  How far apart are the sensors?

Comment: Id like the update speed to be almost instantaneous. But a full loop at .25 sec if I had to multiplex should be acceptable. (you beat me to one of my follow up questions) The closest some would be are about 1/2 inches but that shouldn't be an issue the magnets are really tiny (unless there could be an issue with update frequency or something)

Comment: Do you want to measure magnetic field strength or just detect the presence of a magnet?

Comment: Just detect presence. Kinda new to all this and the DRV5057 was the first thing I found that looked like what I wanted. I know enough to get around but hadn't gotten to the stage of thinking about wiring all of them up to the MC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### PWM Output eg TI DRV 5057

A high-performance possibility would be to use a very small microcontroller per sensor.  The Texas Instruments [DRV5057](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv5057.pdf) sensor you're considering is around 1 to 1.5 EUR, a very small MCU such as an [ATTiny 9](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/atmel-8127-avr-8-bit-microcontroller-attiny4-attiny5-attiny9-attiny10_datasheet.pdf) is under 0.5 EUR, so it might be reasonable.

The sensors output PWM at 2 kHz.  The smallest CPU of this type is 6-pin: power, ground and four IO.  Use the timer to measure the incoming PWM, and put the MCUs in a chain.  You organise a synchronous serial transmission of the data from the main CPU.  If each device is sending say 2 bytes of data, 50 devices x 16 bits x 2 kHz = 1.6 Mbit/sec, easily within performance of the MCUs.

- Advantages: quite easy to do, high performance, possibilty of synchrnous sampling, reasonable price, flexible, available in PTH versions for breadboarding.
- Disadvantages: Designing the communications format, coding and programming the devices.  it's a little heavy handed.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fu12rZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

### Chain of Single Digital Output eg TI DRV 5023

If you're using a simpler sensor such as Texas Instruments [DRV 5023](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv5023.pdf) which just has a single output, consider using a chain of shift registers.  It's a very similar idea, but *much* simpler.  You could use a parallel-load part such as a [74xx165](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd74hct165.pdf), as in the following sketch, also shown with passives per DRV5023 datasheet.

- Advantages: much simpler and cheaper, no firmware to make, can clock as fast as your signal layout will support
- Disadvantages: obviously not PWM, larger chip might be inconvenient on board space

[image]

### Matrix of Single Output Devices

Finally, you could consider conventional multiplexing array, in the manner of a keyboard matrix, perhaps with shift registers for the row driver and column sensor.  Pay attention to the current requirements for each row (DRV5023 uses about 3 mA) and select appropriate family of driver.  Also, pay attention to how fast you can switch the devices on.  Obviously you could use fewer columns, perhaps 4, and just use 4 MCU pins and omit the input shift register.

- Advantages: maximum sensors per auxilary chip, maybe save power as not all sensors are on at the same time
- Disadvantages: need to scan rows means more software on master CPU, can't latch simultaneous sensor values, possibly slow due to sensor start up timing

[image]

You can save an MCU pin by using the same output for `DOUT` and `/LOAD`.

Comment: Oh interesting. Im wondering if this might also work for me https://www.ti.com/product/DRV5023 if im reading it correctly the signal is low in the presence of a magnet and high in the absence of one. The way they will be set up is that there would normally be a magnet present so if one sensor doesn't have one the signal for the row/column would go high. Would this work?

Comment: I've updated my answer.  You probably could use a wired-or to get several sensors on one wire, but you're building in a lot of assumptions about the magnetic arrangement that way.  Perhaps the shift register solution in my edit is a good compromise.  Can I ask what's the application?

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much for your help! Im working on an alternative keyboard. 4 sensors to 1 switch. So they will change the switch output. If a certain magnet is not present then the switch would type "b" instead of "a" for example. I have the mechanics working with a single sensor but then realized I need to set them up in a way to use less pins.
Which of your solutions would you recommend for this?

Comment: Which one to do?  I'd try to use single output (DRV 5023) instead of PWM if I could get the sensitivity correct (ie, magnet triggers sensor with appropriate movement).  Then problably shift reg per 8 (second diagram)., which has nice wiring.  As the sensors are clustered in fours, I might consider a shift reg each 4, not 8, if it made the layout or physical design easier.  A lot depends on if you're making a PCB for the whole unit or smaller subsections.

Comment: Thank you so much! Lots more to learn. PWM isn't necessary just a noob mistake not thinking far enough ahead about what type of signal I really needed.
I am curious about the third option with multiplexing. The switching specifications seem to fast enough. If my math is correct here. The choke point is the output delay time which is 25us. (the rise and fall time are both measured in ns) 25 characters a second is faster than the fastest typing speed ever recorded and would allow for a 40000us loop which is 5000us per row at 8 rows which is a ton of extra time.

Comment: It would save space. The more complex wiring doesn't bother me too much. The only thing I'm worried about is what you mean by "can't latch simultaneous sensor values" do you mean each sensor would have to be fully reset before the next one could be read? Would throwing some diodes in the mix like a regular keyboard matrix fix this?

Comment: "can't latch simultaneous sensor values" = you read each row at a slightly different time, not simultaneously.  For a keyboard this doesn't matter at all.  If you use something like an ATMega32u4, you have enough pins to do the row/column directly, no extra shift regs, and can use the USB as HID (Good project to look at is [kmani314](https://github.com/kmani314/ATMega32u4-HID-Keyboard))

Comment: Sweet! I think that might be the way then. I've worked with ATMega32 before for an led cube but am currently using the ESP32 Saola 1. Thank you for that reference and again for all of your help.
(If you were curious I'm making my own version of this https://hackaday.io/project/178232-lalboard-ergonomic-keyboard)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146820/discussion-between-jonathanjo-and-arkyris).